# Without Url Change redirect from one domain to another domain

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

i want to redirect a domain to another domain but without change the URL.

For Example:

```
ADomain.com redirect to BDomain.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/?xxx=xxxx
```

i was tried some htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?ADomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://BDomain.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/?xxx=xxx [R,L,NC]
```

This code was redirect perfectly . But it's change the current browser url (`ADomain.com`) to the original link (`BDomain.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/?xxx=xxxx`). but i don't need it. i just want to keep the url ADomain.com. please guide me any one. thanks advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I redirect to a different domain without changing the URL in the address bar?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987343/how-can-i-redirect-to-a-different-domain-without-changing-the-url-in-the-address)

Comment: Proxy pass is not the right answer there.

Comment: then how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this PHP code into index.php

```
<?php

function dwn_prt($url,$user_agent='Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)') 
{ 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $user_agent); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://ADomain.com');
$result = curl_exec ($ch); 
curl_close ($ch); 
return $result; 
}
  echo dwn_prt('http://BDomain.com/xxx/xxx/xxx/?xxx=xxxx');
?>
```

Comment: this is working only for home page. If i click any link on home page it will not work. how can i solve that issue