# Forward domain with masking without using iframe

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess, iframe

I own two domains. domain.net is for my main website, and domain.com.au is just a vanity URL. How can I forward users to domain.net when they type in domain.com.au while keeping domain.com.au in the URL bar? I have control of both domains and I don't want to use an iframe. both domains are on 2 separate hostings. com.au-godaddy; .net-1and1

from what i have read goDaddy is com.au in an iframe at .net , which prevents the site from recognizing device width and being mobile friendly.

Comment: Use `mod_proxy` (the `P` flag).

Comment: please elaborate a bit more as i don't have massive idea on programming

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22220902/1626250) which shows you how to proxy your request through the secondary domain. (Should also work when on different hosts - let me know if it doesn't.)

Comment: do i do this in .net or .com.au htaccess file?

Comment: In the .com.au one. Will post as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following in your `.htaccess` file for example.com.au:

```bsh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com\.au$
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.domain.net/$1 [P]
```

This uses `mod_proxy` to pass your request from the `.com.au` domain to the `.net` domain - the `P` flag is provided to allow you to do this.

Comment: Then perhaps `mod_proxy` is not enabled on your server. You would be better off changing your vanity domain's DNS to point to the main server instead. Proxying does have its security woes, so DNS would be the better way to go.