# Is it possible to redirect full domain URL to another domain using htaccess, but without changing the URL?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Let's say I have 2 sites:

site1: https://people.uni.com/johnwick

site2: https://johnwick.github.io

Is it possible to redirect users from site1 to site2 using only .htaccess (I don't own either domains), and that the URL from the user's perspective do not change after the redirect (i.e. the user still sees https://people.uni.com/johnwick in his browser)?

If it is possible, how can I do this?

Comment: I overlooked the "user's perspective do not change" part and only understood you want to carry the URL path. Of course this should never be possible for security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, found my answer here: [How can I redirect to a different domain without changing the URL in the address bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/987343/how-can-i-redirect-to-a-different-domain-without-changing-the-url-in-the-address)

The answer is no. Just shows how much people even bother to read what I wrote (if it's not obvious enough, no, I am not just looking to redirect site1 to site 2).